# What actions would cause a record to be locked?

Tags: case, locking

Yesterday, some Users experienced an error when attempting to change the Owner on open Cases using the Salesforce interface. This issue lasted for about an hour. Afterwards, updating the Owner on Cases worked normally, but we're at a loss as to what caused the error.

Here's the error message they received: "The record you are attempting to edit, or one of its related records, is currently being modified by another user. Please try again."

What would be some possible causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause would be Apex code using the `FOR UPDATE` clause on a SOQL query. That would certainly generate that message. See [Locking Statements](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm)

Locking the record for an entire hour seems a bit odd, unless there is a race condition that is constantly causing deadlocks.

Capturing the debug logs for multiple users when the error occurs may give you some clues about the source of the deadlock.

Salesforce also publishes developer documentation containing all of the things that can cause a record lock. See the [Record Locking Cheatsheet](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/record_locking_cheatsheet.pdf).